# Alter Database recovery model & Shrink log, DB dynamically

Tags: sql-server, scripting, tsql

I normally do on daily basis these operations in GUI

> - Alter database to simple recovery model
> - shrink log file
> - shrink database file
> - Alter database to full recovery model

I can understand script but can't write one.

**I just want to give DB name then script must execute above tasks and possible show log of it**

Declare @DBname varchar(50)
Set @DBname = 'AdventureWorks'

After these 2 lines

Comment: Ummm... why not just leave the database in the Simple Recovery model? Why are you switching back and forth?

Comment: @joeqwerty, so that in future i can do tail log back up in case of failure.

Comment: Is your proposal any easier than leaving the database in full recovery and taking log backups throughout the day?

Comment: @BenThul  ,yes I hope so

Comment: Sorry, are you mistaken us for a code writing service? Writing trivial scripts like this is baseline knowledge for admins. And no, we are not a code writing service.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below Dynamic T-SQL statements:

```
DECLARE @exec nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @db  nvarchar(max) = N'AdventureWorks';

SET @exec = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + N' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE';
EXEC sp_executesql @exec;

SET  @exec = N'DBCC SHRINKFILE (' + QUOTENAME(@db) + N')';
EXEC sp_executesql @exec;

SET  @exec = N'DBCC SHRINKFILE (' + QUOTENAME(@db) + N'_log)';
EXEC sp_executesql @exec;

SET @exec = N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@db) + N' SET RECOVERY FULL';
EXEC sp_executesql @exec;
```

Add this code to a [SQL Server Agent job](https://database.guide/create-a-sql-server-agent-job-using-ssms/#:%7E:text=Create%20the%20Job%20Assuming%20you%20have%20the%20appropriate,the%20process.%20This%20opens%20the%20following%20dialog%20box%3A), that will keep a history of the executions. You can later make a right click on the job and see its execution history.

The database files will be shrinked to the size specified when the files were created.

Make sure AdventureWorks and AdventureWorks_log are the logical names of the database files.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I already using this daily basis . Now what I expecting I don't want mention db name again and again , instead  how about we use a variable. Which stores my db name and does exactly what you wrote.now I just need to mention db name only once  So is this possible if so how ?

Comment: @Shadow777 Let me know if the changes I made to my initial answer is what you are looking for